# show and hide content on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html page and I want to show and hide content on button click.

HTML:

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper">

  <p>
    <button class="learn-more">Learn More</button>
    <button class="learn-more">Learn More</button>
    <button class="learn-more">Learn More</button>
    <button class="learn-more">Learn More</button>
 </p>

<p class="hide_paragraph" id="p1" style="display: none;">First paragraph</p>
<p class="hide_paragraph" id="p2" style="display: none;">Second paragraph</p>
<p class="hide_paragraph" id="p3" style="display: none;">Third paragraph</p>
<p class="hide_paragraph" id="p4" style="display: none;">Fourth paragraph</p>

        </div>
```

Also my function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.wpb_wrapper p .learn-more').click(function(){

    $('.wpb_wrapper p .hide_paragraph').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('paragraph_id')).show();

});

});
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: `$(this).attr('paragraph_id')).show();` no such thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no attribute called `paragraph_id` in your button tags, so your `$(this).attr('paragraph_id')` returns `undefined`. Since `paragraph_id` is not a standard HTML attribute, I advise against simply adding it. Instead just add to each button a data-attribute like so:

```
<button class="learn-more" data-paragraph-id="#p1">Learn More</button>
```

and in your handler use `$(this).data('paragraph-id')` to identify the paragraph to be shown.

Notice that the hash sign is included so you don't have to use the string concatenation anymore. Simply call:

```
$($(this).data('paragraph-id')).show();
```

Comment: Now I have   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.learn-more').click(function(){
        $('.hide_paragraph').hide();
        $((this).data('paragraph-id')).show();
    });

});  But it doesnt work

Comment: @ВасяПупкин You forgot the `$` before the `(this)`.

Comment: This one should be the answer +1 - here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/1njuL4xr/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('elem').click(function(){
  var getIndex = $('elem').index(this);
  $('elem2').hide();
  $('elem2:eq"' + getIndex + '"').show();
 });
});
```

Should work, hope it is exactly what you want :)